# Send text from EditText to TextView on button click, add formatting if radiobutton/checkbox is checked

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, android-button

I'm trying to make a program that takes user text input and displays it in a textview, while also being formatted depending on which radio button(s) and/or checkbox(es) has been checked.

Here's my entire code for mainactivity.java

package com.example.lab3_lefelhocz;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView messageTextView;
EditText inputEditText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioBlack:
            if (checked)
                // Text is black.
                messageTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        case R.id.radioBlue:
            if (checked)
                // Text is blue.
                messageTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;
        case R.id.radioRed:
            if(checked)
                // Text is red.
                messageTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                break;
}
}
public void inputEditText(View view) {        
    if (inputEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
         String editTextValue =   inputEditText.getText().toString();
           messageTextView.setText(editTextValue);
    } else {
         inputEditText.setText("");
         messageTextView.setText("");
}
}
    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem? :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your trying to capture clicks to your EditText by using the onClick attribute in your XML.  I don't think this works for what your tyring to do.  You want to look for key presses rather than clicks.  Try putting a listener on your EditText in your oncreate.  Something like the following.

```
inputEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            inputEditText(v);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I wanted my program to do this: When the user clicks on the button, whatever they entered in the edittext is what is displayed in the textview, with formatting dictated by which radio button(s) are checked as well as which checkbox(es) are checked.

Comment: So inputEditText() is the click listener for your button?  It might help if you post your XML and also explain what isn't working.  Do you get errors?  Is the color not changing?  Is the text not displaying?

Comment: I think i see your problem (or another problem).  You are doing `if (inputEditText.getText().toString().equals(""))` when I think you want to be checking for a NOT empty string.